# Batch file: count duplicate ids and write them in column of csv

Tags: loops, csv, batch-file, automation, preprocessor

I am currently trying to automate the preprocessing process on a csv file via a batch file. I have the following table:

```
id;street;name;nrOfIds
4014001;T1;example1;0
4014002;B2;example2;0
4014003;B3;example3;0
4014004;L1;example4;0
4015001;M3;example5;0
4015002;B9;example6;0
4016001;T4;example7;0
4016002;L2;example8;0
4016003;L1;example9;0
```

The first row "id" holds the id of the entry which is made unique by the last 3 digts (for example 001, 002, 003, ...). The digits before the last three digits are not unique. As you can see in the result table, I want to count how often the first part of the ID (so the part before the last three digits) exists in the table and I want to write the sum into the third column named "nrOfIds". The result table then should look like this:

```
id;street;name;nrOfIds
4014001;T1;example1;4
4014002;B2;example2;4
4014003;B3;example3;4
4014004;L1;example4;4
4015001;M3;example5;2
4015002;B9;example6;2
4016001;T4;example7;3
4016002;L2;example8;3
4016003;L1;example9;3
```

For example, the part before the last three digits of the first line (4014) exists exactly 4 times in the whole table, so I write 4 in the "nrOfIds" column and so on.

The code used for this looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=;" %%a in (%PREPROCESSING_INPUT_PATH%%INPUT_FILENAME%) do (
   (echo %%a;%%b;%%c)> "%PREPROCESSING_INPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%" & goto :file
)
:file
(for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3* delims=;" %%a in (%PREPROCESSING_INPUT_PATH%%INPUT_FILENAME%) do (
  REM count ids (like 4014, 4015, ... and write sum into "nrOfIds" column
  ) 
) >> %PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%


pause
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thank you very much in advance! Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this related to the solution I provided yesterday? Seems to be, so if it is, copy the code into this question and also any possible attempt to resolve this question, else it will be closed as off topic. If you do that, I can help.

Comment: hey gerhard! No it not really is. It is just another preprocessing step I need to make.Maybe you can help me again? I would be very thankful as I am not very experienced with writing batch files!

Comment: @Gerhard I have copied the code (parts of which are written by you in yesterdays question). I believe there needs to be a nested loop which counts the duplicate IDs, but I do not know how to do this within a batch file. greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: If I had a solution based on an utility (command line), is it ok for you? Or is it must be a batch script?

Comment: Hey @aborruso , it has to be a batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty similar to the previous answer I posted, here we just use `find /C` to identify the number of occurrences of the last 3 digits of the ID:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "infile=z:\folder31\testcsv.csv"
set "outfile=%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%testOutput.csv"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%infile%") do (
    (echo %%a)>"%outfile%" & goto :file
)
:file
(for /f "skip=1 usebackq tokens=1-4*delims=;" %%a in ("%infile%") do (
    set "match=%%a"
    for /f %%i in ('findstr /B "!match:~0,-3!" "%infile%" ^| find /C "!match:~0,-3!"') do (
    set /a _cnt=%%i
    echo %%a;%%b;%%c;!_cnt!
  )
 )
)>>"%outfile%"
```

Debug version:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "infile=%PREPROCESSING_INPUT_PATH%%INPUT_FILENAME%"
set "outfile=%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%infile%") do (
    (echo %%a) & goto :file
)
:file
(for /f "skip=1 usebackq tokens=1-4*delims=;" %%a in ("%infile%") do (
     set "match=%%a"
 for /f %%i in ('findstr /B "!match:~0,-3!" "%infile%" ^|find /C "!match:~0,-3!"') do (
     set /a _cnt=%%i
     echo %%a;%%b;%%c;!_cnt!
  )
 )
)
pause
```

Comment: hey again, I have discovered a little bug. When the input file has empty column values, then the output file will not copy the empty cells from the csv. Instead, the values from the next column are copied into the empty cells. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Would only the first column in a row be empty? or the entire row?

Comment: I have various input files. And in one input file I tested today there are now values in the column name. So in the output file the column "name" has the values of the next column (which is nrOfIds). In the output csv file, it should write ;; for empty cells. for example 4014001;T1;;4. But now it writes 4014001;T1;4

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but in these files, is the entire row empty, or just the first column?

Comment: neither nor, the column "name" is empty, which is the third column

Answer (score 0):

This method is simple and run fast:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Count ids
for /F "skip=1 delims=;" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "id=%%a"
   set /A "count[!id:~0,-3!]+=1"
)

rem Update the file
set "header="
(for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=;" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if not defined header (
      echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d
      set "header=1"
   ) else (
      set "id=%%a"
      for /F %%i in ("!id:~0,-3!") do echo %%a;%%b;%%c;!count[%%~i]!
   )
)) > output.txt
```

A method based on external commands, like `findstr` or `find`, is slower...